# Servlet code worked befor 2 days but now not working properly for image retrieval

Tags: jsp

I have written a servlet program to retrieve an image and display it on a jsp page. The code has worked 4 days before. For the past 2 days, I have a problem in tomcat server, so I reinstalled tomcat server. Now the code is not displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the Jsp page is not displaying it may be due to the change in `port` number when you installed the `tomcat server`.

If Apache tomcat server is working correctly and if the page is running without image it would be because of the build file which was generated by the last tomcat server.

Options you can try
Delete cached data from browser
Try running all class files